# How to create a bootable x86_64 program?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, low-level

**Some background**:
I am a Computer Engineering major attending school right now, and I just completed a project that created a microprocessor with a super simple instruction set that ran on an FPGA. I chose to implement a simple file storage scheme, a VGA text only display output, and a PS/2 keyboard input. I wrote two main programs, a firmware that was in ROM in the processor and a kernel that provided a bunch of library type functions, and was capable of loading and executing files from the filesystem. This project was challenging and overall a lot of fun.

**My Question**:
I want to do some super low level programming on a modern computer, but I can't seem to find any resources or documentation that help me get started. To be clear, I want to find the proper documentation that would help me to write a program in C, x86, or x86-64 assembly that I could compile, and format into some form of bootable data. I know this is a daunting task, and typically not something a hobbyist would take on, but I know that it's possible ([Terry Davis's TempleOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS)).

Are there any websites or books that I can read that will contain the specifics needed to make something like this?

Comment: Q: Exactly what do you want to write?  It sounds like a [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting)?  NOTE: In your project  1) You had some kind of system board with a processor, a storage device.  2) The board had some firmware (BIOS?) to allow the system to load the OS from storage and start running it on the CPU.  3) Once the OS was running, you could run your "other" software - programs, drivers, etc etc.  Here's an example bootloader: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/66-develop-boot-loader

Comment: You can try studying similar programs e.g. memtest (https://github.com/Distrotech/memtest86) & grub (https://github.com/coreos/grub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look out, you might just catch the bug.  OS Development, though having a very small demographic, is still quite a thriving hobby.  Once you start, you may not ever give it up.

Since your subject line states 64-bit and you use the term modern hardware, be advised that modern hardware no longer has the older style BIOS, where the developer wrote the boot process which included the video out, file system in, and other standard routines.  Modern hardware now uses an EFI firmware which does all of the booting for you, including the reading from the file system(s).  For modern hardware, OS development really starts with the OS Loader, the part that loads the OS, and this is done in a high level language such as C/C++.  Very little if any assembly at all, in fact that is its point/purpose.

Don't get too discouraged, currently a lot of computers still allow the old style boot.  However, the old style boot starts in 16-bit mode, moves to 32-bit mode, then if desired, moves to long mode (64-bit).  There also are emulators that you can use so you don't have to have a separate system, just to test your development.  I prefer [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) myself, but I am a little bias since I wrote some of the code for it, namely most of the (original) USB emulation.

If you wish to dip your toes into this hobby, there are numerous places to start.  [I personally wrote a few books on the subject](http://www.fysnet.net/osdesign_book_series.htm).  They show you how to start from when the time the POST gives up control to your boot code, up to the point of a minimal Round Robin style task/thread switching OS, with all the necessary hardware and software basics to do so.  There is a [forum](https://forum.osdev.org/) to OS Development, along with its wiki.

Again, a project like this is not for the faint at heart, though it is an enjoyable hobby most have found to be a very good learning experience.